# Enabling multi touch on Windows Phone 8 emulator using Wacom Intuos Pro

Tags: emulator, gestures, touch, windows-phone-8

Using the tablet with the emulator I am able to select and click. Two-finger scrolling and pinch-to-zoom does not seem to register. I can confirm that these gestures work on the Windows 8 start screen and e.g. in Chrome.